# InfoPath cannot submit the error occurred while the form was being submitted

Tags: sharepoint-2007, outlook, infopath, outlook-2007

We recently upgraded an intranet site created in SharePoint 2003 to SharePoint 2007.  After we did that multiple InfoPath Forms began to fail when either open or submitted.  It is unsure if these forms were create in infopath 2003 or 2007 however after recreating one of them, I still get this error when trying to submit.  The submit option uses a data connection that emails me for now (testing).

*InfoPath cannot submit the error occurred while the form was being submitted-To use this feature Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 must be set as the default e-mail program*

Any ideas? And yes, i do have Outlook 2007 on my laptop and it is set to default. This error is received when previewing and when opening from the SharePoint document library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that because the InfoPath form was created in 2003, you can't even copy and paste text boxes from it to a new 2007 form.  When i recreated the form from scratch, it worked correctly.  Assuming the original was corrupted somehow in the SharePoint upgrade.